# Post object using restController

Tags: java, rest, h2

I have small problem to create correctly mathod adding people to teams. The reason is my problem is that i can't add two arguments in requestbody (or PathVariable).
I want to take a person id and team id and return both connected. I create separated class where i generate id but i have problem to imput this correctly id from database: 
This is my method in cotroller:

```
@PostMapping("/addPeopleToTeams/{teamId}/{personId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String addPeopleToTeam(@RequestBody TeamsAndPersonsId teamsAndPersonsId){
        System.out.println(" " + teamsAndPersonsId.getPersonId());
        System.out.println(" " + teamsAndPersonsId.getTeamId());
        teamService.findTeamById(teamsAndPersonsId.getTeamId());
        personService.findById(teamsAndPersonsId.getPersonId());

        return teamsAndPersonsId.getTeamId() + " " + teamsAndPersonsId.getPersonId();
    }
```

This is my method find by id in service:

```
public Optional<TeamDto> findTeamById(Long id) {
        Assert.notNull(id, "ID must exist ");
        return teamRepository
                .findById(id)
                .map(p -> modelMapper.map(p, TeamDto.class));
    }
```

Other my class is Team - this is entity, teamDto, and TeamsAndPersonsId.

TeamsAndPersonsId class:

```
public class TeamsAndPersonsId {

    private Long personId;
    private Long teamId;

    public TeamsAndPersonsId(Long personId, Long teamId) {
        this.personId = personId;
        this.teamId = teamId;
    }

    public TeamsAndPersonsId(){}

    public Long getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(Long personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public Long getTeamId() {
        return teamId;
    }

    public void setTeamId(Long teamId) {
        this.teamId = teamId;
    }
```

How to correctly wrote this controller method to return real team and persons id? Like i add in surce: 
@PostMapping("/addPeopleToTeams/{teamId}/{personId}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use multiple path variables, use them to create a `TeamsAndPersonsId` , then keep the rest of your current code  :

```
    @PostMapping("/addPeopleToTeams/{teamId}/{personId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String addPeopleToTeam(@PathVariable Long teamId, @PathVariable Long personId){

        TeamsAndPersonsId teamsAndPersonsId = new TeamsAndPersonsId(teamId, personId);
        // etc...
```